# How to find different between two similar images using AWS Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

As per my requirement I have multiple images which contains multiple water bottles.By using AWS Rekognition I want to group the water bottles based on color or some other criteria.

I have tried with object and scene detection of AWS Rekognition.But the results are not expected.I want to group as well as based on grouping I want to find the count and later I have to decide whether count increased or decreased.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Rekognition might not be the best tool for this job.

Rekognition can provide **object detection**. For each object it detects, it can provide bounding box that identifies where it is in the picture.

So, you could theoretically perform object detection on a picture, search for objects in the picture and count how many are labelled as being a water bottle. However, it will *not* provide information as to the **colour of the water bottle**.

Your task sounds like something that should be independently trained on sample pictures so the Machine Learning model knows how to **detect the desired features you are seeking** (colour and other criteria). This can be done by using [**Amazon SageMaker**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/whatis.html). It is more complex to use than Amazon Rekognition, but can be trained for specific jobs like you describe.

Your requirement reminded me of a presentation at the AWS re:Invent conference where Amazon.com retail needed to **count items stored on inventory shelves** to identify where items are missing. While counting items might be simple for humans, it actually involves **quite a bit of complexity for computer vision**. I highly recommend you watch this session.

See: [AWS re:Invent 2016: Transforming Industrial Processes with Deep Learning (MAC301) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHUaor0odh4)

Comment: Thanks John,Is there any other ready made api's available to do this job which includes other cloud providers like Azure or GCP?